# How to use same model in multiple partial views in ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm using multiple partial views with same strongly type models in a same page in an MVC 4 application.
i want to call a single action in controller and return the model and use it to all partial views at once, through ajax call.

Comment: Just to make it clear, since you "want to call a single action" that returns the model then what you mean is that the action (most probably) returns a json object? And that you are **NOT** loading the partial views in ajax one at a time?

Comment: yes i'm returning a json object and want to update multiple partial views at single event

Comment: Ok then so you are **NOT** loading the partial views in ajax - you do not have something like `public PartialViewResult PartialView1()`. If that's the case then you can just target the desired elements on each of your partial views. Can you edit your post and include, maybe, two of your partial views so I can give you an answer that will make most sense to you?

Comment: I dont have class as you defined. i have two divs and i want the inner html of each to be updated by same model but from same action. `<div id="first"> </div> <div id="second"> </div>` And i have jquery post where i want to update both divs at once which is similar to below:`$("#myBtn").click(function () { $.post('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', { id: $('#myId').val() }, function (resp) { $("#first").html(resp); $("#second").html(resp); });`

Answer (score 1):

What you gave isn't much but let me try my best and give an example that will make most sense to you. So say you have the following model:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 1 = Premium Users
    /// 2 = Basic Users
    /// NOTE: I'm using int instead of an enum to make the sample more simple.
    /// </remarks>
    public int UserType { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller method that looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
    {            
        IEnumerable<UserProfile> profiles = some_method_that_does_something_and_builds_the_model();
        return Json(profiles);
    }
```

You can do your ajax call like this:

```
    $.post('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', { id: $('#myId').val() }, 
function (result) {
                // you can use $.each here but for loop is more efficient                                   
                var list1 = '';
                var list2 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    // just add the name as p's for a simple example
                    // I build the result as string as it is more efficient than building p elements
                    if (result[i].UserType == 1) {
                        list1 += '<p>' + result[i].UserName + '</p>';
                    }
                    else {
                        list2 += '<p>' + result[i].UserName + '</p>';
                    }
                }
                $("#first").append(list1);
                $("#second").append(list2);
            });
```

Comment: but instead of adding the result values to string, can we call already defined partial view to be loaded or rendered using the obtained model inside if else segment..

Comment: As you said it, the partial view is already "rendered" so you just need to update some of its contents. What I gave you is a simple example to get you started. I'm sure you have a more complex view where you have several html elements.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)? I think that would best suit your needs based on your last comment. You can [get started from here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: yeas i've heard of it but never used it. thank you von v. i'll see what i can do..